# Is it possble to use SSRS for Progress OpenEdge database?

Tags: reporting-services, openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

Is it possible to use SSRS - SQL Server Reporting Services for Progress OpenEdge database?

I'm able to built a report via Microsoft SQL report builder however unable to connect database via ODBC when publishing .rdl file to SSRS

Below is screeshot (first) how I have connected to database through odbc and (second & third) other 2 connecting from report builder which works fine.

[image]

Report builder and Sql report server are on same machine.

However can't see Progress OpenEdge driver on New data Source for SSRS.

Also posted error that i get for .rdl report file uploaded to SSRS but works on fine on same machine report builder.

Please check below,
[image]

[image]

This is what i get,

[image]

Comment: Is the ODBC driver installed on your SSRS server? Has the DSN been created? You should use DSNless connections if possible, as they do not require you to create a DSN

Comment: Are the drivers installed on the SSRS server?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - please check post updated.

Comment: @AlanSchofield - please check original post updated. yes diver is installed

Comment: Firstly use a system DSN not a user DSN. Using a DSNless connection string solves this.

Comment: Actually looks like you already have.

Comment: Connection string : DRIVER={Progress OpenEdge 11.6 Driver};Server=tempserver;Port=12345;Database=tempdb;Uid=guest;Pwd=********;


Error as below,

Couldn't connect
The report server couldn't connect to the data source using the information you entered. Make sure you've entered the connection string and any credentials correctly.
Hide error details 
An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ODBC' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: This page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/data-sources-supported-by-reporting-services-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017#ODBCGeneric says _Although a data provider may support previewing a report on your report authoring client, not all ODBC data providers are designed to support reports published on a report server_ So maybe it just doesn't work

Comment: What edition of SSRS do you have? is it "Express edition with Advanced Services"? I believe you'll need a full edition (Standard) to use ODBC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187158/discussion-between-rohan-and-nick-mcdermaid).

Comment: Start by following this guide: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P131153